# Nginx + Passenger : stop file uploads timing out after 30 seconds

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger, timeout

I have a ruby app which runs under passenger and nginx.  If i try to upload a largish file (eg 15+ meg), when it gets to 30s in, the upload restarts (according to chrome) and at the end of the next 30 seconds it gives up and i get a timeout.

Is there an option i can put in my nginx config to prevent this from happening?  Here's what my current nginx config looks like:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    passenger_root /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript;
    gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";


 server {
      listen 80;
      server_name alekskrotoski.com;
      root /var/www/apps/akrotoski/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
      passenger_enabled on;
   }
}
```

I'm not an nginx expert and have a feeling this might be obvious, hope so anyway.  I already tried adding

```
proxy_read_timeout: 600;
```

to the server block but that didn't help.

Cheers, max

Comment: Please post a log snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and seemed to have fix it by upping the [`client_max_body_size`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) in my server's `http` block:

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 128m;
    ...
}
```